# Transforming a class diagram to a SQL database

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, class-diagram

I have this part of a class diagram that I want to translate into SQL:

Piece of class diagram:

[image]

My internship supervisor sent me this SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `Matricule` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Role` enum('ResponsableProduction','ResponsableChaineProduction','ResponsableMaintenance','AgentMaintenance','Administrateur','Magasinier') NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `responsable_production` (
  `Matricule` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Nom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Prenom` varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `responsable_maintenance` (
  `Matricule` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Nom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Prenom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `RefChaine` varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `responsable_chaine_production` (
  `Matricule` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Nom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Prenom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `RefChaine` varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `magasinier` (
  `Matricule` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Nom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Prenom` varchar(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `agent_maintenance` (
  `Matricule` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Nom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Prenom` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Specialite` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Sexe` enum('Homme','Femme','','') NOT NULL,
  `NiveauEducation` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ExperienceProfessionnelle` int(11) NOT NULL
);

-- Triggers `users`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `User_Insert` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.Role = "ResponsableMaintenance") THEN
        insert into responsable_maintenance(matricule) VALUES (NEW.matricule);
    ELSEIF (NEW.Role = "ResponsableChaineProduction") THEN
        insert into responsable_chaine_production(matricule) VALUES (NEW.matricule);
    ELSEIF (NEW.Role = "AgentMaintenance") THEN
        insert into agent_maintenance(matricule) VALUES (NEW.matricule);
    ELSEIF (NEW.Role = "ResponsableProduction") THEN
        insert into responsable_production(matricule) VALUES (NEW.matricule);
    ELSEIF (NEW.Role = "Magasinier") THEN
        insert into magasinier(matricule) VALUES (NEW.matricule);
    End IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But it didn't seem quite right to me. Because, for example if I'm adding a new user, first I have to add it to the user table, then add his remaining details in one of the other table depending on his role. That seemed a lot of trouble to me, and inconsistency problems might arise later on.
Is this SQL script consistent with the Class Diagram? (after adding the needed PK and FK constraints into it ofc).
And if yes, is there a simpler/safer database design than the one my supervisor sent me?

Comment: Hi - why does the SQL not seem quite right to you? You need to ask a specific question about an issue you are facing rather than a generic “is this right” type of question?

Comment: For example, if I'm adding a new user, first I have to add it to the user, then add his remaining details in one of the other table depending on it's role. That seemed a lot of trouble to me, and inconsistency problems might arise later on.

Comment: 1) You should always update/edit your question with additional information/clarification, rather than via comment, so that all information is in one place and is consistent. 2) In your question you are asking if the SQL matches the diagram but in your comment your are questioning the diagram design - those are 2 very different issues. Can you decide what your actual issue is and then update your question to reflect that? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to match this up because the diagram has very little data, and the sample code has lots of information not included in the diagram. However, two things to note: First, regarding classes represented by multiple tables : the database tables are a storage mechanism and will be optimized as such. Typically, you may have procedures, views, or other queries to transform this data back into an instance representation of the class. Secondly, depending on the development practice, you might leave the SQL to an "ORM" with a "Code First" approach that creates the database structures for you.

Comment: I see you're point, also I apologies for the ambiguity of my post. Gladly, I already found the issue with the SQL database design code and the solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge in implementing your UML diagram into SQL tables, is the inheritance.  Inheritance is not a concept in SQL, and several techniques exist to map such an UML model to a relational model:

- [single table inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance):  you'd have one table for the role that would would contain (nullable) columns for all possible attribute in any roles, as well as a code that helps to know which kind of role the row is about:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `role` (
    `IdRole` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `NomRole` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `TypeRole` enum ('ResponsableProduction','ResponsableChaineProduction', 'ResponsableMaintenance','AgentMaintenance','Administrateur','Magasinier') NOT NULL
    `Specialite` varchar(50)     -- Used only if maintenance agent, NULL otherwise
  );
  ```
- [class table inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html): you'd have a table for each class in the inheritance hierarchy, and relationships of each class with its parent/child classes.  The can be very cumbersome if many classes are empty or have not many differences.
- [concerete table inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html):  you'd have a table for each concrete class but none for abstract parents.  Each table has all the necessary rows: the ones inherited, and its own.

Your supervisor seems to play with you:  he/she used concrete table inheritance, because you have all the role specialisations and not the abstract role.  Unfortunately, it uses rows which are related to user, which is dramatically false.  Moreover with the multiple roles possible, it would mean to duplicate information if a user has several roles.

Once you have sorted out, what really belongs to the role tables, and what belongs to the user table,  you ara ready  to create the n to n [mapping table](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html), between users and roles.

Comment: Yes sir, using single table inheritance makes much more sense to me then the code I was giving. Also, aside from that I found various relatively small issues with the relational model described in the rest of the SQL code my supervisor sent me(which I didn't post). My only problem now is how to tell my supervisor with a Phd in CS that the db he sent me gave me insomnia but in a nice way.

Comment: I was wondering if he/she passed you this model to test your skills or because of his/her own lack of insights in this particular domain of CS. One way to address it would be to explain that you're trying to understand and ask questions. For example, you have understood that the trigger creates a role instance for every new user, but how are additional roles added, especially considering that only one role is stored in the user table. You can also ask why user attributes are repeated in all the tables, and how they are kept in sync if for example the last name would be changed.

Comment: Honestly, I hope it is some sort of test. Also, I will do like you said and focus on those points when presenting my version. 
Thank you my dear sir.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit difficult to understand the complete environment of your questioning, however, I can tell you that the trigger that is being created, which is responsible for creating a record in the corresponding table, according to the role of the new user, is not entirely correct because It only inserts the "Matricule" field but there are more "not null" fields that, by not assigning data to it, would most likely generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the SQL code I provided in my post is not right as I suspected.

The problem is that it doesn't manifest the ability of one user to have one or multiple roles (relationship described by the class diagram).

The solution should be creating:

- User table that hold all the attributes from the different roles.
- Role table that contains all possible roles("responsable production", "magasinier", "administrateur", ...)
- Associative entity/table between User table and Role table.